# user warning messages keep popping up even after uninstall

Tags: 7

I have recently disables, uninstalled and removed a few modules from my drupal 7 site but this error keeps popping up no matter what I do, I have researched how to remove them but to my dismay nothing, please help.

User warning: The following module is missing from the file system: admin. For information about how to fix this, see the documentation page. in `_drupal_trigger_error_with_delayed_logging()` (line 1138 of `/opt/lampp/htdocs/drupal/includes/bootstrap.inc`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably the disabling and uninstalling process of the modules didn't went smoothly. According to [this help page on Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/node/2487215):

> Restore the module and actually disable and uninstall it (recommended if possible): First, restore the module to its original location in the file system. Then either go to the Modules page and disable/uninstall it from there, or use Drush (drush dis module_name && drush pm-uninstall module_name, where module_name should be replaced with the name of the module).

Don't forget to also clear the caches, that "magic" feature also resolves a lot of problems ;)

You could also disable the specific message by using the [Disable Messages](https://www.drupal.org/project/disable_messages) module. However, I would recommend to try cleaning up your Drupal configuration that are causing the messages.

Comment: I cleared the cash and did all the uninstalling correctly. The problem was most likely caused because I transferred some of the modules from a friends PC to mine but in the long run I think it can be ignored so the disable messages module helped. Thank you, Watergate.

Comment: Good to hear you have solved your problem.